# Data Fusion Dataproc compute profle in a different account

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm trying to execute a pipeline on a Data Proc cluster in a different project by the one Data Fusion instance is deployed but I am having some trouble. Data Proc instance seems to be created correctly but the start of the job fails. Any idea on how to solve?

Here the stack trace of the error

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the project where the Google Cloud Dataproc is doesn't have SSH port open. Can you check that your project allow port 22 connection? Cloud Data Fusion uses SSH to upload and monitor the job in the Cloud Dataproc.

Comment: Yes, the project where the Google Coud Dataproc is have SSH port open, unfortunately I'll have to ask to check network where Data Fusion is deployed. Thanks

Comment: Thanks the problem was that SSH port was blocked in Data Fusion network.